# Implement Bus seating chart in ios

Tags: ios, uistackview

I am quite new to ios and lately have been faced with the challenge of implementing a bus seating chart in ios. This chart will allow users to also select preferred seats. I tried this with the stackview and the implementation did not turn out well. Also, the scrollview does not work so I am unable to see any of the components if they have been added at all. Any ideas on how to implement the bus seating chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was on your place, I would implement it using `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` with fixed cell size (I assume that the bus is pretty symmetrical).

Comment: Thanks for this, I was able to implement this with the UICollectionView. Great insight